# Pagespeed - Render Blocking Resources

Tags: javascript, page-speed, load-time

I know there are a few questions on this but I was wondering where I can *actually see* the scripts that are blocking rendering.

Pagespeed Insights will provide a few scripts and CSS, but is there a more technical way to determine this? Waterfalls show request timing and have a duration for blocking, but it doesn't say what the culprit is.

Is there something in Chrome Developer Tools that can help here? I know the Element and Network tabs quite well but not sure if there's more features that can display these.

*or I could be way off*

Can anyone provide resources to where I can look into this further? I'm trying to relay info on how to diagnose the scripts and CSS that are blocking to a developer who has a complex technology stack.

Comment: e.g. https://nooshu.github.io/blog/2019/10/02/how-to-read-a-wpt-waterfall-chart/#third-party-blocking-javascript

Comment: Thanks @Lag, I have some experience with waterfall charts but this seems like it goes in much more depth.